# How to open CJuiDialog from controller class

Tags: yii

I am trying to open a dialog popup after clicking view button in YII Framework,
I am struck while calling CJuiDialog from YII controller action of view.

Please provide solution for this ,

Comment: What do you have so far? Please show us some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here no need to consider Controller as you are trying to integrate the Widgets which is a part in YII View.

Check bellow script to generate a `JuiDialog` when you click on the button

```
        <?php
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
            'id'=>'Exe1',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'My Dialog',
                'autoOpen'=>false,
                'show'=>array('effect'=>'fadeIn','duration'=>100),
                'hide'=>array('effect'=>'fadeOut','duration'=>100),            
            ),
        ));
            echo 'Hello...!';
        $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
        ?>

        <button onclick='$("#Exe1").dialog("open");'>View</button>
```

Comment: I need to call action in CButton Class view by passing grid view id